# SVG does not render in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, svg

for a better understanding, you can visit [this Kotlin web ide](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/or8lkdfir18sspjqd39jmk739e/bo6dvfvss5fn32868e3b8h2ct6).
I was fiddling around, testing some things and I want to display a red circle (you can try it, when you click on Run on the upper right).
The generated code looks like this, and works quite well.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" style="display:flex; width:100%; height: 100%">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></circle>
</svg>
```

But when you actually click "Run", the SVG is NOT rendered in the appearing iFrame and I cannot find out why:

[image]

the full iframe code is shown here:

```html
<iframe src="/static/kotlin/1.3.50/iframe.html" class="k2js-iframe">
 
 <html style="height: 100%"><head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="kotlin.js"></script>
    <script>
        if(kotlin.BufferedOutput !== undefined){
            kotlin.out = new kotlin.BufferedOutput();
        } else {
            kotlin.kotlin.io.output = new kotlin.kotlin.io.BufferedOutput();
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0">
<html>
<head>
 <title>HTML encoding with Kotlin </title></head>
 <body><a href="http://jetbrains.com/kotlin">Kotlin </a>
<p>This is some <b>mixed </b>text. For more see the <a href="http://jetbrains.com/kotlin">Kotlin </a>project </p>

<div style="display: block; height: 100px; width: 624px">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" style="display:flex; width:100%; height: 100%"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></circle>
</svg>
</div>
<p>some text <ul><li>1*2 = 2 </li><li>2*2 = 4 </li><li>3*2 = 6 </li><li>4*2 = 8 </li><li>5*2 = 10 </li></ul></p></body>
 </html>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to wrap around the SVG file? I (and probably most people here) really don't want to click on external links.

Comment: Yes of course, I edited the question

Comment: By the way. You can savely click the link. It’s to JetBrains web ide. Nothing private or suspicious

Comment: Hi @gutenmorgenuhu, I'm facing a similar issue. Were you able to fix it?